# animation track with two stripes and second stripe strart where first stripe ends?

Tags: animation, nla-editor, actions

How to work with animation and tracks (stripes)?
I create Stash and Track in Notlinear Animation. I add two Action Stripes (from created Action Stash) in one Track. How to do the second Stripe starts (rotation and location) where the first Stripe ended?
Is it possible? 
Or am I trying to work wrong with tracks and stripes? And I have to create every animation step by step and again and again and I cannot reuse already created parts of animation?

Here is simple example what I mean:
1: create Cube in 0,0,0; create key frame in frame 1 (I) = Location
2: move Cube to 1,0,0 in frame 20; create key frame = Location
3: click on buton Stash in Action Editor

4: Add Tracks in Notlinear Animation (track will be named NlaTrack)
5: Add Action Strip in NlaTrack track and this step I will repeat (I will have got in NlaTrack two CubeActions)

Now I Play track NlaTrack and I will see cube is moving from 0,0,0 to 1,0,0 and jump to 0,0,0 and moving to 1,0,0.
What I am asking is can the second strip in track continue where previous strip ends? It means first stripe move cube from 0,0,0 to 1,0,0 and second stripe should start from 1,0,0 to 2,0,0.

Comment: I don't know if it's doable with the NLA, it doesn't look like there's a Cycle modifier in the NLA, but if it is as easy as going from 0,0,0 to 1,0,0 then go to 2,0,0 etc, you can do it without the NLA: Select the action in the Dope Sheet, switch to the Graph Editor with Ctrl Tab, on the left panel choose the track that you want to repeat (X location), open the N panel > click on the Modifiers tab, choose Cycles, and for After, choose Repeat With Offset

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it (Cycle modifier) will not work when the second stripe will move another axis (eg. from 0,0,0 to 0,1,0).

Comment: you can restrict the frame range, but yes, not always very convenient, but maybe explain the situation, you could for example parent your animated object to an empty and move the empty, etc...

Comment: If I understand well, there is no possible to create Stripe (animation) and reuse it whenever I want? If I prepare a Stripe, I have to modify starting position of every stripe depending on final position of previous stripe and this modification I have to do by hands (there is no automatic way). And this modification I can do in Graph Editor. Is it correct?

Comment: I don't know if you can do it the way you want in the NLA, but if for example you want to make a character walking through a scene, which is a problem pretty close to yours, you need to create a walk cycle (the legs move but the character doesn't move forward), then make the armature follow a curve. For this particular kind of animation, follow path is the way to go. That's why it would be interesting to know what you're trying to do, because there must be a solution.

Comment: I have got no exact situation, I just try to understand how to work with NLA, Dope Sheet, Action Editor, tracks, etc. It is little bit confusing. I tried to test it and I just found out when I use two Tracks and set Strip:Blending=Combine it works, how I expect. First Track with Stripe move cube from 0,0,0 to 1,0,0 and in second Track with same Stripe continue from 1,0,0 to 2,0,0. So I suppose I cannot put all into one Track, but I have to create and use multiple Tracks.

Comment: I don't really understand your solution, maybe give the answer in the Your Answer field  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I to solved my problem:
I create Stripe with cube moving from 0,0,0 to 0,1,0. I create first Track with added this Stripe and second Track with this Stripe. I set Blending = Combine in Second Track. So the second Stripe begins when the first Stripe ends. At the end of the Tracks is cube on the position 0,2,0.

[image]